# How does Rust return large types (before optimisation)?

Tags: rust, function-call

With a function signature such as:

```
pub fn hash(input: &[u8]) -> [u8; 32]
```

how do those 32 bytes get passed to the calling function?  (Before optimisation, which might place some parts in registers.)

Possibilities include:

- On the stack, with the calling function having to copy them into pre-allocated space in its own stack frame.
- On the heap, with a generated `free()` inserted into the calling function.
- Some, per-thread, statically allocated buffer.

Just curious, I have no need for this information.  The answer may differ by architectures.

Comment: Unless the large value is placed in a container which uses the heap, or is place in a `Box`, that value is on the stack. Rust won’t allocate unless explicitly told

Comment: It's not defined, the compiler can do whatever it wants to, there is no Rust calling convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is neither a copy nor a heap allocation involved.

The caller function allocates space for the value on its stack. The callee takes an additional hidden parameter, the address of the return value. It writes the value there. The caller passes the address of the allocated space on its stack as the value for the hidden parameter.

Of course, none of that is guaranteed. This is just how it happens to work right now.

Comment: FWIW the caller allocating space for the return value is part of the x64 calling conventions when returning a struct larger than 128b (64b in MS calling conventions), so while there's no guarantee the language will use that for non-FFI functions, or that it will construct the return value directly in that space, it's a pretty good assumption: the language would need good reasons to bother differing and diverging from the standard system ABI(s).

Comment: Also the caller doesn't pass the address of the allocated space on the stack, but as the first parameter register (RDI), shifting everything else. In both SystemV and MS conventions, the callee also has to return the pointer it got via RAX.